# receive d3.js offset mauseclick coordinate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, canvas

I want to save click cordinate on var.
I have this code. This code doing draw line.

```
var vis = d3.select("#canvas--zone").append("svg")
    .attr("width",640)
    .attr("height",360)
    .on("mousedown",mousedown)
    .on("mouseup",mouseup)
    .on("mousemove",function () {
        console.log(d3.mouse(this));
    });
```

how I can save click coordinate on values(like X and Y coordinate)
Like that:

```
.on("mousemove",function () {
        var x = $(this).offset().left;
        var y = ${this}.offset().right;
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing the Event parameter

```
.on("mousemove",function (e) {
   var cursorX = e.pageX;
   var cursorY = e.pageY;
 });
```